# How to send message from the js library to a group in Azure SignalR Serverless

Tags: signalr, serverless, asp.net-core-signalr, signalr-client

Hi I'm trying to send a message to a group using the Azure Signal R Serverless JS Client [Js Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aspnet/signalr).

I can do this from the Azure Serverless Function as simply as:

```
await signalRMessages.AddAsync(
                new SignalRMessage
                {
                    GroupName = m.GroupName,
                    Target = m.Target,
                    Arguments = new[] { m.Message }
                });
```

*where signalRMessages = IAsyncCollector signalRMessages

**How can I send this same message from the js library?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems like this is now possible ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-serverless-development-config#sending-messages-from-a-client-to-the-service

> Sending messages from a client to the service If you have upstream
> configured for your SignalR resource, you can send messages from
> client to your Azure Functions using any SignalR client. Here is an
> example in JavaScript:

JavaScript

`connection.send('method1', 'arg1', 'arg2');`

Answer (score 2):

> trying to send a message to a group using the Azure Signal R Serverless

You can refer to [this github repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-signalrservice-extension/blob/dev/samples/simple-chat/content/index.html) that shows with sample code how to implement group broadcasting functionality in Azure functions with Azure SignalR Service.

***Add user to a group using the `SignalRGroupAction` class***

```
return signalRGroupActions.AddAsync(
    new SignalRGroupAction
    {
        ConnectionId = decodedfConnectionId,
        UserId = message.Recipient,
        GroupName = message.Groupname,
        Action = GroupAction.Add
    });
```

***On client side, make request to endpoint to add a user to a group***

```
function addGroup(sender, recipient, connectionId, groupName) {
        return axios.post(`${apiBaseUrl}/api/addToGroup`, {
          connectionId: connectionId,
          recipient: recipient,
          groupname: groupName
        }, getAxiosConfig()).then(resp => {
          if (resp.status == 200) {
            confirm("Add Successfully")
          }
        });
      }
```

***Test Result***

[image]

**Updated:**

Q: "send the message from the JS Client straight from the socket".

A: From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-serverless-development-config#sending-messages-from-a-client-to-the-service), we can find:

> Although the SignalR SDK allows client applications to invoke backend logic in a SignalR hub, this functionality is not yet supported when you use SignalR Service with Azure Functions. Use HTTP requests to invoke Azure Functions.

Comment: Thanks! The answer you posted here is how to join a group... I got all of that working as well as sending a message to a group (via HTTP trigger) What I want to do is send the message from the JS Client (straight from the socket)

Comment: `The answer you posted here is how to join a group` If you check the github repo I shared, you would find complete sample code. And [function sendMessage](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-signalrservice-extension/blob/dev/samples/simple-chat/content/index.html#L103) could help send message to specific group.

Comment: `What I want to do is send the message from the JS Client (straight from the socket)` From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-serverless-development-config#sending-messages-from-a-client-to-the-service), you can find: *"Although the SignalR SDK allows client applications to invoke backend logic in a SignalR hub, this functionality is not yet supported when you use SignalR Service with Azure Functions. Use HTTP requests to invoke Azure Functions."*

Comment: Thanks, seems like it's not supported yet.  I have no issues sending using HTTP requests... If you update the answer with this info, Ill mark as the correct answer.